# Trying to use $cond to $sum and $subtract

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My documents:

```
_id:"DwNMQtHYopXKK3rXt"
client_id:"ZrqKavXX8ieGpx5ae"
client_name:"luana"
companyId:"z3ern2Q7rdvviYCGv"
is_active:true
client_searchable_name:"luana"
status:"paid"
items:Object
id:912602
gross_amount:1000
type:"service"
description:"Pedicure com Zé (pacote)"
item_id:"bjmmPPjqKdWfwJqtC"
user_id:"gWjCskpHF2a3xHYy9"
user_id_commission:50
user_id_amount:0
use_package:true
quantity:1
item_costs:Array
discount_cost:Object
 type:"package"
 value:100
 charge_from:"company_only"
entity_id:"LLRirWu5DabkRna7X"
created_at:2019-10-29T10:35:39.493+00:00
updated_at:2019-10-29T10:36:42.983+00:00
version:"2"
created_by:"2QBRDN9MACQagSkJr"
amount:0
multiple_payment_methods:Array
closed_at:2019-10-29T10:36:52.781+00:00
```

So i made a $project:

```
{
  _id: 0,
  closed_at: 1,
  serviceId: "$items.item_id",
  serviceAmount: "$items.gross_amount",
  discounts:"$items.discount_cost"
}
```

And then $group

```
 _id: {
    month: { $month: "$closed_at" },
    serviceId: "$serviceId",
    discountType: "$discounts.type",
    discountValue: "$discounts.value"
  },
  totalServiceAmount: {
    $sum: "$serviceAmount"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make a $sum of values of the categories in my DB, actually i filtered all the data, so i have exactly what i need, like that;

```
_id:Object
"month":10
"serviceId":"MWBqhMyW8ataGxjBT"
"discountType":""courtesy"
"discountValue":100

"totalServiceAmount":5000
```

So, i have 5 types of discounts on my DB, they are: Percentage (discount in percentage), courtesy (make the service amount 0), package (make the service amount 0), gross (gross discount of value) and null if there's no discount o value.

so, if the type of discount is;

Percentage: I need to subtract the discountValue for the totalServiceAmount (discountValue will be in percentage, how i do that subtract if total serviceAmount is on gross value)

Courtesy and package: I need to transform the totalServiceAmount in 0 value.

Gross: i need to subtract the discountValue for the totalServiceAmount.

Null: just let totalServiceAmount.

I tried like that, to make some test, but i really don't know if i'm goign to the right path, the result was null for every amountWithDiscount.

```
{
    $project: {
    {
    amountWithDiscount: {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        $eq: ["$_id.discountType", "null"]
      },
      then: "$serviceAmount", else: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: ["$_id.discountType", "gross"]
          },
          then: {
            $subtract: ["$serviceAmount", "$_id.discountValue"]
          },
          else: "$serviceAmount"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Make sense?

Comment: Can you provide some documents from your MongoDB collection?

Comment: @Haruo, yeah i will put on the post

Comment: I dont understand the rules about the Courtesy and Package types. Can you provide an example with the value of 'amountWithDiscount' for this scenario?

Comment: @Haruo yes! Actually, courtesy is when a final cliente comes to one of ours establishment and we give him a "courtesy" and give a service for free. 

And "package" is when a final client buy a package in one of ours establishment, "package" a group of services selled together for a ship price, so the final cliente pays all the price before, and when he will do the service he will pay nothing more because he payed before the full price of package, so de the value must be 0. But in the document we save the price of the service and have thoses fields os discount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a collection with your grouping result:

**01)** Example of Documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5db9ca609a17899b8ba6650d",
    "month": 10,
    "serviceId": "MWBqhMyW8ataGxjBT",
    "discountType": "courtesy",
    "discountValue": 0,
    "totalServiceAmount": 5000
  },
  {
    "_id": "5db9d0859a17899b8ba66856",
    "month": 10,
    "serviceId": "MWBqhMyW8ataGxjBT",
    "discountType": "gross",
    "discountValue": 100,
    "totalServiceAmount": 5000
  },
  {
    "_id": "5db9d0ac9a17899b8ba66863",
    "month": 10,
    "serviceId": "MWBqhMyW8ataGxjBT",
    "discountType": "percentage",
    "discountValue": 10,
    "totalServiceAmount": 5000
  },
  {
    "_id": "5db9d0d89a17899b8ba6687f",
    "month": 10,
    "serviceId": "MWBqhMyW8ataGxjBT",
    "discountType": null,
    "discountValue": 10,
    "totalServiceAmount": 6000
  }
]
```

**02)** Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      discountType: "$discountType",
      amountWithDiscount: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$discountType",
              null
            ]
          },
          then: "$totalServiceAmount",
          else: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  "$discountType",
                  "gross"
                ]
              },
              then: {
                $subtract: [
                  "$totalServiceAmount",
                  "$discountValue"
                ]
              },
              else: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$discountType",
                      "percentage"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $multiply: [
                      "$totalServiceAmount",
                      {
                        $subtract: [
                          1,
                          {
                            $divide: [
                              "$discountValue",
                              100
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  else: "$totalServiceAmount"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

A working example at https://mongoplayground.net/p/nU7vhGN-uSp.

I don't know if I fully understand your problem, but
take a look and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very so much, you helped a lot, i make some changes but i followed that example and have done right! 

Have a nice day my friend!